# Read a xml file inside .zip file on Amazon S3 without downloading the big zip file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zip, sentinel

I have a lot of .zip files on Amazon S3, they are big and I don't need to download all of them. I only need the unique xml file inside them to know which file should be downloaded.

This is the case for Sentinel 3 data `xfdumanifest.xml`, e.g:

```
s3://s3-olci/LFR/2018/01/31/S3A_OL_2_LFR____20180131T225040_20180131T225340_20180202T040253_0180_027_215_2520_LN1_O_NT_002.zip/S3A_OL_2_LFR____20180131T225040_20180131T225340_20180202T040253_0180_027_215_2520_LN1_O_NT_002.SEN3/xfdumanifest.xml
```

Anyone knows how to read only this `xfdumanifest.xml` file without downloading the whole zip file?

Comment: At best you can stream the Zip file and read the one file you need.  But that means that you'll need to read all of the Zip file up to the entry you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 doesn't support downloading and extracting just one file from a ZIP.